# Cloud DataFlow always maxes out at 15 workers?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible when to know when the autoscaling feature is limited by some IAM quota on Google Cloud DataFlow? I'm finding that many of my tasks, regardless of size, boot time, whatever, will grow until they hit 15 workers. It could be a coincidence, but I doubt it. I can turn autoscaling off and set the num workers to 50 without a problem, so there isn't an explicit quota limit i'm hitting.

[image]

Quotas don't seem to be an issue.

[image]

but even large tasks seem to always hit 15 workers. When I manually set 40 workers, the tasks finishes much faster, which I know doesn't exactly mean that autoscaling isn't working, but is concerning.

Comment: did you need to do anything othe than adding --maxNumWorkers to your pipeline options?

Comment: @Ben_Chambers had it right its --max_num_workers in python that worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default maximum number of workers for autoscaling is currently 15. If you would like to allow it to scale to more workers, you can use the `--maxNumWorkers=` option.

Comment: Should this just be set in the `pipeline_options` or is there a different place that this flag needs to be set?

Comment: I believe if you set a higher --maxNumWorkers from either the command line or the in the pipeline options it should allow it to scale up, assuming you have sufficient quota.

Comment: I set this in the pipeline options and I still maxed out at 15 workers.  I'm guessing that I don't have sufficient quota -- what resource should I be increasing? This article suggets to review compute engine quotas (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/quotas) but it's not clear which I need to adjust.  Google Compute Engine CPUs in us-central1 shows 0/600, persistent disk has 40,960 GB (which suggests 100+ CPUs), 100 in-use IPs, 500 managed instance groups and 1000 instance groups which all suggest I should be able to exceed 15 workers. Is there some resource quota that I am missing?

Comment: After some further debugging, it looks like --maxNumWorkers is not actually being set (at least according to the pipeline options in the cloud UI) -- further I checked the exec options here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params and realized that maxNumWorkers does not show up in the python SDK, but it does in the Java SDK -- is this option not available in python?

Comment: It looks like in Python the option is [--max_num_workers](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/a3a7807fec68a7954ba136dc00499649d372f5ca/sdks/python/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.py#L417).

Comment: Is this still true in 2019, and where is this documented?